# How to use the result of a function in a Vim keymap?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, key-bindings

I have a function in Vim script that returns a string.

```
" Return first directory with ".git" folder, if none is found
" return the current directory
function! s:project_root()
      for vcs in ['.git']
          let dir = finddir(vcs.'/..', expand('%:p:h').';')
          if !empty(dir)
              return dir
          endif
      endfor
      " If there is no root dir use the current dir
      return expand('%:p:h')
  endfunction
```

I would like to use this function in a key mapping as the argument to a command called `Files`. So something like this

```
nnoremap <leader>f :Files<Space><insert result of function call here><CR>
```

I tried doing:

```
execute 'nnoremap <leader>f :Files<Space>'.s:project_root()
```

but I believe this only calls the function once (when the .vimrc is loaded), when I need the function to be called everytime the keybinding is pressed.

Comment: `nnoremap <leader>f :Files s:project_root()<CR>` should work. I can't get what a problem you are facing.

Comment: I tried that, and I'm pretty sure it just interprets `s:project_root()` as the directory name itself, instead of calling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the `:execute` inside your mapping instead.

You don't need to use `<Space>` in mappings, you can just use an actual space instead.

You probably want to include a `<cr>` at the end, to actually execute the `:Files` command and not leave it pending on the command line waiting for you to press enter (but, again, maybe that's what you want?)

Putting it all together:

```
nnoremap <leader>f :execute 'Files '.<SID>project_root()<cr>
```